# Passing props to a cloned child element giving Unknown Prop warning

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have an AdminLayout in react which is in turn loading children elements in this fashion:

```
class AdminLayout extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      flash: { msg: "some message", type: undefined}
    }
  }

  updateFlash(flash){
    this.state.flash = flash
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <FlashMessage flash={this.state.flash} />
        <NavBar/>
        { React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {updateFlash: this.updateFlash})}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The idea here is that I intend to have my child elements update the flash state in the AdminLayout. However, with the code `{updateFlash: this.updateFlash}` I am receiving the following error:

```
Warning: Unknown prop `updateFlash` on <div> tag. Remove this prop from the element. For details, see https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html
    in div (created by Grid)
    in Grid (created by LocationEdit)
```

I've looked at the documentation, I don't believe that I am doing any of the cases. I am also not trying to set the prop directly on any divs.

Has anyone seen something like this before?

Hrm... It may also help to know what my inner component looks like. I've tried to strain out anything non-necessary...:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import AdminLayout from '../components/layouts/AdminLayout'
import LocationsSource from '../sources/LocationsSource'
import {Button, Grid, Row, Col, FormGroup, FormControl, ControlLabel, HelpBlock} from 'react-bootstrap'
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

class LocationEdit extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)

    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      location: {
        name: "",
        site_link: "",
        description: ""
      }
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    let data = this.state.location

    if(data._id != undefined) {
      LocationsSource.update(data).then((response) => {
        browserHistory.push('/admin/locations/');
      })
    } else {
      LocationsSource.create(data).then((response) => {
        browserHistory.push('/admin/locations/');
      })
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if(this.props.params.id)
      LocationsSource.find(this.props.params.id).then((result) => {
        this.setState({loading: false, location: result})
      })
    else{
      this.setState({loading: false, location: {}})
    }
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    let change = {location: this.state.location}
    change['location'][event.target.name] = event.target.value
    this.setState(change)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {}

  render() {
    let location = this.state.location

    if(this.state.loading)
      return(
        <AdminLayout>
          <Row>
            <img src="/assets/images/loading.gif" />
          </Row>
        </AdminLayout>
      )
    else
      return(
        <AdminLayout>
          <Grid>
            <Row>
              <Col xs={8} md={8}>
                <h2>Location</h2>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col xs={8} md={8}>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <FormGroup controlId={"name"}>
                    <ControlLabel>Name:</ControlLabel>
                    <FormControl onChange={this.handleChange} name="name" type="text" defaultValue={location.name} />
                  </FormGroup>
                  <Button type="submit">
                    Submit
                  </Button>
                </form>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Grid>
        </AdminLayout>
      )

  }
}

export default LocationEdit
```

Comment: What is `updateFlash` and what's the parameter `flash`? You cannot set the state the way you did.

Comment: @Chris updateFlash is a function, I want to call it from a child component when I want to update the flash message in the layout. Ideally, I wanted to pass flash message info to the admin so that it would intern pass that to the flash message component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the source of the problem ended up being that I was using react-router incorrectly.  It was impossible to see until I added the last part of the question where it shows that I was rendering the `AdminLayout` from a sub-component `LocationEdit`.

I was doing this because with react-router I was loading that page directly, I didn't realize that I actually needed to load the layout first and the children pages needed to be defined as child tags. What follows is the original route I had and the changes I made:

```
render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/admin/" component={Locations} />
    <Route path="locations" component={LocationEdit} />
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Changes:

```
render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/admin/" component={AdminLayout} >
      <Route path="locations" component={LocationEdit} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Then I took the `AdminLayout` tag out of my LocationEdit page. I have a feeling that it was trying to load the `props` directly onto the `<Grid>` tag instead of on the actual component as I had thought.

Answer (score 0):

```
  updateFlash(flash){
    this.setState({ flash });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <FlashMessage flash={this.state.flash} />
        <NavBar/>
        { React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {updateFlash: this.updateFlash.bind(this)})}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: I appreciate the `this.setState`, that seems like the better way to set the state. I still get the same error though.